# android virtual device manager won't open

Tags: android, sdk

I was creating a new AVD and once I press OK after making required, the AVD window stopped responding, I restarted eclipse and re entered to the virtual android device manager would not open, please help

Comment: "Creating a new sdk" means what? Could you please explain in more details what you have done?

Comment: I mean a new emulator, normally i use the nexus S, but the new one was a nexus 7 @WarrenFaith

Comment: Delete it and create it again. Uncheck snapshot options. Show the error message shown in the Console window. Try starting the emulator with `adb`.

Answer (score 0):

try go to avd manager --> select the current avd --> click delete
and then create new one with the same properties and start it again.

Comment: hmmmm .. what is the message you have when you open your avd manager?

Comment: there is no message, nothing appears, just won't open :( @KhalidTaha

Comment: try re-installing the SDK Manager